# [Math]Three downward lines for similarity

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

I am looking for a similarity or equality operator used in Euclidean mathematics. For example `ABC ||| DFE`.

I don't know if it is used at all outside of school in my country, since I could not find any use of it outside of my textbook.

It is basically `\equiv` just rotated 90 deg.

EDIT: This is specifically for `amsmath` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

⦀ is U+2980 and `\Vvert` in unicode-math and stix packages, but you could also just use `|\,|\,|` or some other space to suit requirements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\myeq{\mathrel{|\mkern1mu|\mkern1mu|}}

\begin{document}


$ABC \myeq XYZ$
\end{document}
```

Comment: What would that be in amsmath, or is there no equivalent?

Comment: @Longtomjr as far as I can see the ams fonts don't have the character but `|\mkern1mu|\mkern1mu|` should be fine, using whatever space you think best (if `\,` is too much)

Comment: @Longtomjr I added an amsmath definition

Comment: On a mildly unrelated note, is using unicode-math fine in most cases?

Comment: @Longtomjr that depends. in most cases I use pdflatex so unicode-math is not an option. if you are using luatex or xelatex it may be an option but typesetting with unicode opentype math fonts is still in its infancy and the systems are not really production ready yet (both luatex and xelatex have had fairly big fixes made to their opentype math setting within the last year) also if submitting to a journal then (usually) pdftex is a requirement currently. So it's probably the future but perhaps we are still in the past:-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I am mostly just using Latex to make reference sheets for my math and sciences. I use pdflatex for these sheets because I don't need any funky font functionality. I think I will go with the workaround. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

The spacing is the same as in `\parallel` if you use `\mkern -1.2mu`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\similar}{%
  \mathrel{|\mkern-1.2mu|\mkern-1.2mu|}%
}

\begin{document}

$ABC\similar DFE$

$ABC\parallel DFE$

\end{document}
```

[image]